# Socle of submodule relative to the module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, socle

[image]

in these notes i am reading i am told that the socle of $K$ (where $K \subset M$ , and $M$ is a module) is = $K \cap$ Soc $ M$

But why is this? i see the intuition but cannot formalize a proof

any help would be great
thanks

Comment: What's the theorem that this is a corollary of?

Comment: if f is the R homomorphism $f:M \longrightarrow N$  then f(soc) $\leq$ Soc N @AviSteiner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to see this.

First, one characterization of the socle of a module $N$ is that it is the sum of the simple submodules of $N$.  The simple submodules of $K$ are exactly the simple submodules of $M$ that lie in $K$.

Second, using the theorem you stated in the comments let $f\colon K \to M$ be the inclusion map.  Then that theorem gives $\mathrm{soc} \ K \subseteq \mathrm{soc} \ M$ and clearly it's in $K$ so $\mathrm{soc} \ K \subseteq K \cap \mathrm{soc} \ M$.  But $K \cap \mathrm{soc} \ M$ is semisimple and a submodule of $K$ so $K \cap \mathrm{soc} \ M \subseteq \mathrm{soc} \ K$.  Hence they are equal.

Comment: ah of course, it makes sense thank you!

Comment: Also, just out of interest is there any way i could use this fact to show that given $ 0 \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow P$ is exact, then $0 \longrightarrow soc(M) \longrightarrow soc(N) \longrightarrow soc(P)$ is exact ?

Comment: Yes, this is how you show exactness at $\mathrm{soc} \ N$.  Since the maps are restrictions the kernel of $\mathrm{soc} \ N \to \mathrm{soc} \ P$ is $\ker(N \to P) \cap \mathrm{soc} \ N$.